# pdal truncating values when writing ply

Tags: point-cloud, pdal

When using pdal to either translate to ply file or split a ply file in smaller chunks, it appears to be truncating values so I end up with point clouds with stripping. This does not occur with other formats - but I need .ply in particular.

E.g. when splitting up a bigger file....

```
 pdal split --capacity 1000000 in.ply out.ply
```

... I end up with the result below for the subsets. Are there parameters that may stop this from happening? (See the below pic)

[image: point cloud with missing values/strips]

Comment: I had similar problem when translating LAS to PLY, and what worked for me was to use a pipeline instead of the direct PDAL command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a precision problem where PDAL trim automatically some decimals.
You need to control that with this option : `--writers.ply.precision=6f` (it say to the ply writers to have 6 decimals)

Comment: Excellent thanks very much!